# Date Validation in JSF & Richfaces

Tags: jsf

I m using a rich:calendar to display Date in my application
But some how date validation isn't working properly in a particular  scenario.
i.e it some one enters date as 05/05/2010sfc in this case it  automatically trims the extra characters in the end
and displays date properly in next page instead of giving an error of  invalid date on same page.

It works in other cases such as asd05/05/2010, 05sfa/05/2010, etc

I tried using  but it didn't help

Can anyone please help me on this...

Comment: isn't this better than showing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed how [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (which it is using *under the hoods*) by default works.

Best what you can do is to restrict the input field max length to 10 or supply a custom date validator.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it helped in solving the problem/question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

I used this tag to restrict the length to 10 characters:

```
< rich:calendar value="#{myBean.date}"datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy" enableManualInput="true" inputStyle="width:80px">
    < f:attribute name="maxlength" value="10"/>
< /rich:calendar>
```