# JSF: <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="mm/DD/yyyy"/>

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I have a JSF date component using convertDateTime and it accepts "12/12/2013ab"

the backing bean returns "12/12/2013" as date

may I know how can I prevent user from entering "12/12/2013ab". It will prompt an error for 12/1a/2013.

Comment: Please show the component you're using. Plain JSF doesn't provide a date component.

Comment: R you using any calendar component?

Comment: Is that a problem if the application automatically trim bad characters at start and end? Ortherwise I suggest implementing a JSF validator. Also here is another question like yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194817/date-validation-in-jsf-richfaces

Answer (score 5):

Provide a custom date converter which also checks the input length.

```
@FacesConverter("myDateTimeConverter")
public class MyDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    public MyDateTimeConverter() {
        setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.length() != getPattern().length()) {
            throw new ConverterException("Invalid format");
        }

        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

}
```

*(please note that the [pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is `MM/dd/yyyy` and not `mm/DD/yyyy`)*

Then, instead of

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

use

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date}" converter="myDateTimeConverter" />
```